# Discrepancy between CloudQueue ApproximateMessageCount and Azure portal UX

Tags: azure, azure-storage-queues, azureportal

There seems to be a significant discrepancy between Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Queue.CloudQueue.ApproximateMessageCount property value and what is shown in the Azure Storage Queue UI in the Azure Portal (portal.azure.com).

The CloudQueue property indicates there are many hundred messages in the queue, while the UI shows either zero or a handful.

How approximate is the ApproximateMessageCount the SDK exposes? Is it possible that high ingress/egress would account for such a large difference?

Comment: Where in  Azure Storage Queue UI in the Azure Portal  you can see number of messages?
I only can see a list with the message "Only the first 32 messages are displayed."

Comment: Only in Azure Storage Explorer(downloaded from  https://github.com/microsoft/AzureStorageExplorer/releases/  )
"Showing 32 of 341881 messages in queue"

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the portal is showing you, but the call to `ApproximateMessageCount` is going to return the (fairly close) current count of all messages in the queue at that time (including invisible messages).

If your app is rapidly inserting or ingesting queue messages, this number cannot really be pinned down exactly (which is why it's *approximate*).

It's entirely possible that the portal isn't refreshing very often. IIRC there's a 'refresh' button on the queue view in the portal.

Comment: Thanks David. I did refresh a number of times in the portal and saw messages coming and going. It's still a small number of them at any time. We are investigating using the message latency (time when message was picked up minus the message's visibility time) as a metric to monitor instead of the number of messages in the queue.